# While showing a progress from 0 to 100 %, how do I only show it if the number meets some criteria?

Tags: javascript

I have a running process on server that downloads a file. While downloading it, I get updates as the percentage, like `0`, `12.5`, `27.8` and finally `100`.

When I receive current progress value, I send it to client via websocket channel. Though, I don't want to send it every time backend gets the value updated, but only when it meets some criteria, e.g. increases by at least 10. This means I skip sending all the values, but send some of them.

What's the approach I should use here?

Comment: `if (newValue - lastValue >= 10 || newValue == 100) { send(); }`?

Comment: What I would do is from the server end is use some form of debounce..  What backend are you using?  eg. if your backend was say node -> https://www.npmjs.com/package/debounce

Answer (score 0):

You could create a reusable wrapper to filter out "duplicate" values:

```
 function ensureDifference(diff, fn) {
  let previous = Infinity;
  return function filterDifference(v) {
   if(Math.abs(v - previous) < diff) return;
   previous = v;
   fn(v);
  }
}
```

Usable as:

```
 const updateProgress = ensureDifference(10, function updateProgress(progress) {
   socket.emit("progress", { progress });
 });

 updateProgress(5);
 updateProgress(10); // won't trigger
 updateProgress(16); // will trigger
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a closure to keep a record of the previous progress value.

```
function progressTracker(rangeSize, callback) {
    let prevProgress = -1
    return function progressFilter(value) {
        let current = Math.floor(value / rangeSize)
        if (current > prevProgress) {
            prevProgress = current
            callback(value)
        }
    }
}
```

In the following code snippet the callback will be executed only once for values in each range of 10.

```
// Replace this with your own callback function
function logProgressCallback(progress) {
    console.log(`progress: ${progress}`)
}

const progressLogger = progressTracker(10, logProgressCallback)

progressLogger(0.25) // progress: 0.25
progressLogger(9.1) // no output
progressLogger(10.1) // progress: 10.1
progressLogger(19.9) // no output
progressLogger(29.9) // progress: 29.9
progressLogger(30.1) // progress: 30.1
```

The difference between the successive progress outputs may not be 10 but there will be only a single output for each range.